# 4.8.0 - How to avoid singles content to be duplicated accross all sites

Tags: localization, craft4, singles

How to avoid singles content to be duplicated accross all sites ?

What are the best propagations rules in the single section and the fields ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to avoid singles content to be duplicated accross all sites?

Singles only exist once, so they don't have propagation settings. You can only choose the sites in which to enable the single section, and the single entry will be propagated to all of them.

You can, however, use translation settings for the fields you use in the single section. For example, if you set each field to be translatable for every site, the field values in the single entry will not be propagated between the sites.

> What are the best propagations rules in the single section and the fields?

There are no objectively good or bad settings. It depends on what you want to achieve in terms of content modelling and author experience.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I setup single with "translate for each sites" fields. Event that, I noticed a different behaviour between Craft 3.7.38 and 4.8.0. In 3.7.38, the content entry wasn't duplicated through all sites activate the single, therefore in 4.8.0, the content is duplicated to all sites, I just need to activate the single as empty to new sites. So is it a new behaviour ?

Comment: @emiliezawadzki Haven't checked out Craft 4.8 yet, but I don't think it changes anything regarding this behaviour. What you might be seeing is the initial propagation of an entry, this always uses copies over the current values of the entry (otherwise, you would get a completely empty entry). So if you activate a single on a new site, you _might_ get contents from another site copied over once (not quite sure though). However, the fields will not be synced again as long as the translation settings are configured accordingly.